# Deleting a FreeDraw layer leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I have a leaflet map on which I have created a FreeDraw layer to select regions. But once the FreeDraw layer is added, I am not able to do the normal map functionalities like moving through the map or zooming the map. In order to do those works, when I try to remove the FreeDraw layer from the map:

```
map.removeLayer(freeDrawLayer);
```

When the above code is executed after selecting a region, the freeDrawLayer still exists and I am not able to move through or zoom the map. How can I remove the FreeDraw layer from the map, whilst displaying the selected regions?

Comment: Does the developer console display any errors?

Comment: @IvanSanchez there are no errors on console on removing the layer.

Comment: In that case, you'll have to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so people can dig deeper into the problem. As of now, there is not enough information.